# Wikitude: License key is missing or invalid

Tags: cordova, wikitude

I just registered as a free trail of wikitude four days ago, and I'm following the tutorial here:
[SETUP GUIDE CORDOVA CLI](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/phonegap). I copied and pasted the key they sent me to the WikitudePlugin.js as they did in the tutorial. But when I build and run my project, it just gave we a watermark of "License key is missing". I was really confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `cordova build` to build the android project, your WikitudePlugin.js will not be built into the project for some reason. So how I solved this problem is to copy and paste the key in `~/<Project Name>/platforms/android/platform_www/plugins/com.wikitude.phonegap.WikitudePlugin/WikitudePlugin.js` again after I build my android project.

Comment: don't use the `platform_www` folder but the `www` folder instead. Changes you make to files in the `www` folder should not be overwritten.

Comment: You are right, and can you explain the reason why my key configuration didn't get build when I run `cordova build`?

Comment: Im sorry @LingboTang but what do you mean about copy and paste the key? Like build the project and then delete the WikitudePlugin.js and then add it again? I have the exact same problem. I dont now whats wrong with my build. Thanks.

Comment: @Kinari Good question, I'm assuming you have a grunt or gulp task manager to build the project. I think what you should do is you copy the license key that they sent you after you build the project. Because if you go to this `WikitudePlugin.js` after you build the projects, you will see the key you have is not in the built files. Copy your key again in the file should solve your problem.